# If $f(X) = a_0 + a_1 X + a_2 X^2 \in \mathbb{F}[X]$ then show $f$ is uniquely determined by $f(x)$, $f(y)$, $f(z)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, determinant

This is the exact question:

[image: Question]

It's part(ii) that I don't understand - what does it mean and what is it asking me to do? How would I go about constructing a proof? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, suppose you are given three distinct values of $x,y,z$. Then, can you find $a_0,a_1,a_2$? What kind of *linear* system could you set up? Can you use part $(i)$ to show it has a unique solution?

**SPOILERS AHEAD**

That is, you're given that

$$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2=c_0=f(x)$$
 $$a_0+a_1y+a_2y^2=c_1=f(y)$$
 $$a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2=c_2=f(z)$$

You can write this as $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x &x^2\\1&y&y^2\\1&z&z^2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a_0\\a_1 \\ a_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} c_0\\c_1 \\ c_2\end{pmatrix}$$

Use $(i)$ to show the determinant is nonzero.

Comment: Surely x=y=z= the values of $a_0$,$a_1$,$a_3$ substituted into the quadratic formula?

Comment: Could I use Cramer's rule?

Comment: @Mathlete I added something.

Comment: How would I show the det is non zero? And then by showing that, can you say the LHS of the expression has a non-zero matrix and thus a unique solution?

Comment: I just gave the solution away. If you have a linear system $\bf Ax=\bf b$, then $\bf x=\bf A^{-1}b$ when $\bf A$ is invertible. But when is $\bf A$ invertible? Look at $\det\bf A$ to decide.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being very silly - of course the det is non zero as x,y,z are distinct.